# Can I use Apple CloudKit JS in a Cordova app on non-iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cloudkit

Now that Apple has [made CloudKit JS available](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKitJS/Reference/CloudKitJavaScriptReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015359), would I be able to use it in a Cordova / Ionic app?

Specifically, (how) would the (iCloud) user authentication work on non-iOS devices? (I assume all users would have to have an iCloud account.)

Answer (score 1):

Users will be able to sign in with their Apple ID and if they don't have one they can register right in the popup authentication screen that Apple is providing for CloudKit on the Web -- New users without any IOS devices get an initial 1G of free personal storage.

Comment: Thanks - my (main) concern is that a (legitimate) popup asking for their iCloud credentials could be regarded as scam / phishing attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's only JS, I don't see anything that would impeach you from using it within Cordova. It's made to be implemented in web-apps, and almost anything that a web-app can do, Cordova can do it too.